# Searching a SharePoint 2007 list, which also returns matching substrings

Tags: 2007, search, web-part

I'm having issues with the provided Search WebParts. I'm currently using the "Text Filter" WebPart because it is the closest to what I need.

The problem with that one is that it only searches through one of the columns in the list. I need it to search the entire list. But most importantly, I need the user to be able to enter a substring and it to return results. For example, if I enter "pro" I expect stuff like "proclaim" or "production support" to return, but it is not matching anything.

Is there some better WebPart to do this? I'd prefer an oob solution, if possible. Any info would be helpful.

Thanks
-V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointsearch/thread/2529ba3e-9cd6-4f83-9258-435fedfc1e96